# Change config file in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have `phpmyadmin` installed in this location `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`. Database is running on localhost. So, I can access database from phpmyadmin without any changes. I want to change localhost to different host or add additional host.

For this, I tried to change `config.inc.php` file and add below code:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'xxx-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'xxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'xxx';
```

But, It's not connecting with that host. Where should I change this information?

One strange thing I noticed is when I removed `config.inc.php`, still `phpmyadmin` was working. But, may be its because of localhost default settings.

Comment: When all else fails there is always the `phpMyAdmin` manual

Comment: Or search Stack https://askubuntu.com/questions/19973/how-to-configure-phpmyadmin-to-access-multiple-servers

Comment: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';` might well need changing to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Also changed that. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your original localhost settings in phpMyAdmin

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MySQL localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3306;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

All you do is add another block to setup another selectable connection

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MySQL on Amazon';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xxx-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3306;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

But you should check that your remote Amazon MySQLServer is using port 3306 as standard, and that there is a user account setup that is allowed to connect from a remote location.

> And of course restart Apache after making this change.

Comment: That's what I did. Everything is correct from Amazon side. I just want to know Am I trying to edit different config file? Because second host is not visible even after editing the file

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making the amendment to `config.inc.php`

Comment: Yes. I did. `phpmyadmin Version information: 4.0.10deb1` This might help.

Comment: Oh.. I found it. I was keep editing `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file. But, real config is inside `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. But, Why is it like this?